# Spring Boot Test on JsonMappingException gives subpar stacktrace

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

A spring integration test, that's defined as

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = HiVssFormioWrapperApplication.class, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@TestPropertySource(locations= {"classpath:application.properties", "classpath:application-integration-test.properties"})
```

started failing recently, however the stacktrace gives little clue as to where to look for. It does say what's wrong, but not where. Here is full stacktrace, notice how there literally is not a single stacktrace element, that would be pointing to our code:

```
org.opentest4j.MultipleFailuresError: Multiple Failures (2 failures)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of io.vavr.collection.List out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.gera.gsm.hivssformiowrapper.domain.periodpackage.DataPackage["department"]->com.gera.gsm.hivssformiowrapper.domain.Submission["data"]->com.gera.gsm.hivssformiowrapper.domain.Department["fillableForms"])
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of io.vavr.collection.List out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.gera.gsm.hivssformiowrapper.domain.periodpackage.DataPackage["department"]->com.gera.gsm.hivssformiowrapper.domain.Submission["data"]->com.gera.gsm.hivssformiowrapper.domain.Department["fillableForms"])
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.TestRun.getStoredResultOrSuccessful(TestRun.java:179)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunListenerAdapter.fireExecutionFinished(RunListenerAdapter.java:211)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunListenerAdapter.testFinished(RunListenerAdapter.java:177)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunListenerAdapter.testFinished(RunListenerAdapter.java:76)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.SynchronizedRunListener.testFinished(SynchronizedRunListener.java:56)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier$7.notifyListener(RunNotifier.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier$SafeNotifier.run(RunNotifier.java:72)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier.fireTestFinished(RunNotifier.java:187)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.EachTestNotifier.fireTestFinished(EachTestNotifier.java:38)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:40)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:80)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

I get suspicious of `MultipleFailuresError` as perhaps it's what swallows the proper stacktrace, but googling "disable junit MultipleFailuresError" didn't bring anything useful.

This probably isn't issue with eclipse, because running with maven from command line gives similar result.

The versions used are

- Java: OpenJDK13
- SpringBoot: 2.2.0.RELEASE

  Looking at dependency hierarchy, this brings in

  - junit 4.12
  - jackson 2.10
- Vavr: 0.10

Answer (score 0):

The exception is says that Jackson, the JSON Serializer, cannot serialize the Vavr List class.

You must add Vavr Jacksion support to make this work.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.vavr</groupId>
    <artifactId>vavr-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>0.10.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have it, and it all used to work. It currently fails, because it encounters START_OBJECT token instead of START_ARRAY for the list. 

**But my question is not about that**. My question is why the stacktrace doesn't point in any way to my code